# Get JSON Object Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, firebug

I am building my application based on another similar application.
I am using firebug to attempt to get the same Response / JSON.

In the working application the "Response" tab says:
[image]

and the "JSON" tab shows several JSON objects with associated properties:
[image]

In the broken application the "Response" tab says:
[image]
(It put a "d" key around the data and escaped all the double quotes)

and the "JSON" tab just shows a single object d that contains a string of the data:
[image]

The method that is called to return the "broken" JSON response is:

```
    public static string GetMembers()
    {
        Member member1 = new Member();
        member1.Id = 1;
        member1.FirstName = "John";
        member1.LastName = "Smith";

        Member member2 = new Member();
        member2.Id = 2;
        member2.FirstName = "Bruce";
        member2.LastName = "Banner";

        List<Member> members = new List<Member>();
        members.Add(member1);
        members.Add(member2);

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(members);
    }
```

What can I do to my method to make it return / display the JSON data the same way as the first application?

*Note* I don't have the source of the first application, I am just looking at the page it loads in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

The application puts a d around the data because there is a security vulnerability from passing an array directly to the client.  See this [resource for more information](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx) on why.  That's why the application framework does it.  I think a lot of other serializers require the same...

Your only alternative is to serialize each object, and manually write out the array of objects.  But again, beware of the vulnerability with doing that.